# Join two metrics in PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

Given two metrics:

```
jnxBgpM2PeerIndex{jnxBgpM2PeerIndex="5",dc="A",job="juniper_bgp",instance="AWS-WEST-vSRX-1",jnxBgpM2PeerLocalAddr="1.1.1.1",jnxBgpM2PeerRemoteAddr="2.2.2.2"} 5

jnxBgpM2PrefixInPrefixes{jnxBgpM2PeerIndex="5",dc="A",job="juniper_bgp",instance="AWS-WEST-vSRX-1"} 20
```

Need to have a resulting metric like this:

```
{job="juniper_bgp",instance="AWS-WEST-vSRX-1",jnxBgpM2PeerLocalAddr="1.1.1.1",jnxBgpM2PeerRemoteAddr="2.2.2.2"} 20
```

What would be the proper PromQL join expression?
Thank you.

Tried this:

```
sum(jnxBgpM2PrefixInPrefixes{job="juniper_bgp",instance="AWS-WEST-vSRX-1"} * on(jnxBgpM2PeerIndex,dc,instance,job,target_ip) group_left(jnxBgpM2PeerRemoteAddr,jnxBgpM2PeerLocalAddr) jnxBgpM2PeerIndex{job="juniper_bgp",instance="AWS-WEST-vSRX-1"}) by (dc,target_ip,jnxBgpM2PeerRemoteAddr,jnxBgpM2PeerLocalAddr)
```

But this produced wrong number of prefixes. It shows a way more than 20 (around 300). Probably, something is wrong with the join statement and I cannot figure out.